# What is the motivation behind using a deterministic policy?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deterministic-policy

What is the motivation behind using a deterministic policy? Given that the environment is uncertain, it seems stochastic policy makes more sense.

Comment: A related question: [Is the optimal policy always stochastic if the environment is also stochastic?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/10591/2444).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right! *Behaving* according to a deterministic policy while still learning would be a terrible idea in most cases (with the exception of environments that "do the exploring for you"; see comments). But deterministic policies are learned off-policy. That is, the experience used to learn the deterministic policy is gathered by behaving according to a stochastic behavior policy.

Under some reasonable assumptions--like that the environment is fully-observed and is stationary--an optimal deterministic policy always exists. The proof can be found in chapter 6 of "[Markov Decision Process -- Discrete Stochastic Dynamic Programming](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470316887)" by Martin L. Puterman. The same cannot be said for stochastic polices. For this kind of environment (even if it's stochastic) an optimal policy is hardly ever stochastic.

So, a motivation for wanting to learn a deterministic policy is often because we know that there is an optimal deterministic policy.

It's possible your question was also tangentially about off-policy learning. "Why learn a deterministic policy directly (off-policy) when we can just use something like decaying $\epsilon$-greedy?" Briefly, off-policy learning is very powerful and general. It's necessary in any algorithm that uses experience replay, for example. A discussion about the merits of off-policy learning is probably best left to another question, but reading Section 5.5 of Sutton and Barto's [RL book](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html) should get you started.

Finally, directly learning a deterministic policy could be more computationally efficient if using [deterministic policy gradients](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/silver14.pdf). In the setting with continuous state and action spaces, the deterministic policy gradient exists and has a simpler expectation than the stochastic policy gradient.

Stochastic policy gradient:

$$\begin{align*}
\nabla_\theta J(\pi_\theta) &= \int_\mathcal{S} \rho^\pi (s) \int_\mathcal{A} \nabla_\theta \pi_\theta (a|s) Q^\pi (s,a) \text{d}a\text{d}s\\
& = \mathbb{E}_{s\sim \rho^\pi, a\sim\pi_\theta}[\nabla_\theta \log \pi_\theta (a|s) Q^\pi (s,a)]
\end{align*}$$

Deterministic policy gradient:
$$\begin{align*}
\nabla_\theta J(\mu_\theta) &= \int_\mathcal{S} \rho^\mu (s) \nabla_\theta \mu_\theta (s) \nabla_a Q^\mu (s,a)|_{a=\mu_\theta (s)}\text{d}s\\
& = \mathbb{E}_{s\sim \rho^\mu}[\nabla_\theta \mu_\theta (s) \nabla_a Q^\mu (s,a)|_{a=\mu_\theta (s)}]
\end{align*}$$

Notice that the expectation in the deterministic policy gradient isn't over the action space. Estimating this expectation would require many fewer samples in the setting of a continuous, high-dimensional action space.

To recap:

- Optimal policies are often deterministic, not stochastic
- Learning deterministic policies directly (off-policy) is powerful and general
- It can also be more efficient if in a continuous, high-dimensional action space

Comment: Maybe add second/third bullet points at the end: 2) A stochastic environment does not mean that there is an optimal stochastic policy 3) It is common for there to be no optimal stochastic policy

Comment: I would also like to comment that actually if the environment has enough randomness, it is possible to learn optimal control, on-policy with a deterministic greedy policy. This is how TD-Gammon worked for instance. They key is that the environment adds the necessary state exploration

Comment: @NeilSlater Good points. Edits should reflect those changes.